# Unity VR Player camera not moving when running in real device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am a beginner in Unity and following Udemy tutorials for learning VR using Unity and making a game named **Ninja Slash**. Everything seems to be working fine in the **Unity Editor Play mode** but when I run my app in a **real device**, **my player doesn't move at all**. I can't figure out what is the problem here.

Here is my Player script.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject sword;
public float speed = 4.5f;
public float walkingAmplitude = 0.25f;
public float walkingFrequency = 2.0f;
public float swordRange = 1.75f;
public float swordCooldown = 0.25f;

public bool isDead = false;
public bool hasCrossedFinishLine = false;

private float cooldownTimer;
private Vector3 swordTargetPosition;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    swordTargetPosition = sword.transform.localPosition;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (isDead) {
        return;
    }

    transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        transform.position.x,
        1.7f + Mathf.Cos(transform.position.z * walkingFrequency) * walkingAmplitude,
        transform.position.z
    );

    cooldownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (GvrViewer.Instance.Triggered ) {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (cooldownTimer <= 0f && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit)) {
            cooldownTimer = swordCooldown;

            if (hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy> () != null && hit.transform.position.z - this.transform.position.z < swordRange) {
                Destroy (hit.transform.gameObject);
                swordTargetPosition = new Vector3 (-swordTargetPosition.x, swordTargetPosition.y, swordTargetPosition.z);
            }
        }
    }

    sword.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp (sword.transform.localPosition, swordTargetPosition, Time.deltaTime * 15f);
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collider) {
    if (collider.GetComponent<Enemy> () != null) {
        isDead = true;
    } else if (collider.tag == "FinishLine") {
        hasCrossedFinishLine = true;
    }
}}
```

Here is the screenshot for hierarchy view.

[image]

I tried with different version gvr sdk unity package but I am getting same result everytime and I also tried running it different devices like htc,samsung etc.

Comment: Is the Camera on the same GameObject as your player script? Try placing the Camera on a child of Player instead.

Comment: Player itself is the camera

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't change the transform of the main camera in VR mode. You have to make the maincamera as a child of another object (empty?!) and then move that object.

Comment: I tried that too but that too also doesn't work every time.